# GraphQL and nested resources would make unnecessary calls?

Tags: graphql

I read GraphQL specs and could not find a way to avoid 1 + N * number_of_nested calls, am I missing something?

i.e. a query has a type client which has nested orders and addresses, if there are 10 clients it will do 1 call for the 10 clients + 10 calls for each client.orders + 10 calls for each client.addresses.

Is there a way to avoid this? Not that it is not the same as caching an UUID of something, those are all different values and if you GraphQL points to a database which can make joins, it would be pretty bad on it because you could do 3 queries for any number of clients.

I ask this because I wanted to integrate GraphQL with an API that can fetch nested resources in an efficient way and if there was a way to solve the whole graph before resolving it would be nice to try to put some nested stuff in just one call.

Or I got it wrong and GraphQL is meant to be used only with microservices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the difficulties of GraphQL's "resolver architecture". You must avoid incurring a ton of network latency by doing a lot of I/O in each resolver. Apps using a SQL DBMS will often grapple with the N + 1 problem at first. You need to use some batching and/or caching techniques to get around this.

If you are using Node.js on the server, I have two tools to recommend:

- [DataLoader](https://github.com/facebook/dataloader) - A database-agnostic tool for batching resolvers for each field and caching individual records.
- [Join Monster](https://github.com/stems/join-monster) - A SQL-tailored tool that reads each query and your schema and compiles a SQL query for you. It leverages JOINs and DataLoader-style batching to fetch the data from your tables in a few (or a single) SQL queries.

Comment: Thanks, Andy! Probably I won't use node, maybe python or rust but knowing that it is possible from GraphQL's architecture, I will start from there and try to build a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I consider, that you're talking about using GraphQL with SQL database backend. The standard itself is database agnostic, and it doesn't care, how are you going to work out the problems of possible N+1 SELECT issues in your code. That being said, the specific server-side implementations of GraphQL server introduce many different ways of mitigating that problem:

- AFAIK, Ruby implementation is able to to make use of Active Record and gems such as [bullet](https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet) to apply horizontal batching of executed database calls.
- JavaScript implementation may make use of [DataLoader](https://github.com/facebook/dataloader) library, which have similar techinque of batching series of executed promises together. You can see it in action [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c35bj1AT3X8&t=15m42s).
- Elixir and Python implementations have concept of runtime info about executed subqueries, that can be used to determine which data will be further needed in order to execute GraphQL query, and potentially prefetch it.
- F# implementation works similar to Elixir, but plugin itself can perform live analysis of execution tree to better describe, which fields can be potentially used in code, allowing for easier split of GraphQL domain model from database model.
- Many implementations (i.e. PostGraph) tie underlying database model directly into GraphQL schema. In this case GQL query is often translated directly into database query language.

Comment: That is useful not only for SQL backend, if you have an API that can fetch data in one request, it would be kinda bad doing multiple.
As I saw both javascript and python implementation have a cache which only kinda solve for already seen objects, like the user -> friends where friends are also user instance and if you make that nested a lot, it would fix the problem for sure.